# dispatch_sync not working with main queue

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

please consider following code:

```
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

    dispatch_group_t myGroup = dispatch_group_create();

    dispatch_group_async(myGroup, myQueue, ^{
        NSLog(@"First block of code");
    });

    dispatch_group_async(myGroup, myQueue, ^{
        NSLog(@"Second block of code");
    });

    dispatch_group_async(myGroup, myQueue, ^{


        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ //problem here

            dispatch_time_t myTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 10ull * NSEC_PER_SEC);

            dispatch_after(myTime, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                NSLog(@"Third block of code work");

            });
        });

    });

    dispatch_group_wait(myGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    NSLog(@" All done ?");
```

Problem is in `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{`
When i make dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{, it works as it should. Point of making that sync, is blocking main thread for 10 seconds, simulating "hard work". But, unfortunately, its not work. I wonder why?

What i want is: dispatch_sync **block** main thread for only 10 seconds, then execution continues.

What in fact happening: dispatch sync block whole application from any further execution.

Comment: I'm sure dispatch_sync is working exactly as it should, just not as you think it should. It would help if you describe _exactly_ what you expect to happen, and _exactly_ what happens.

Comment: @gnasher729 please see my edits.

Comment: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), is exactly what you should be using anyway...this is how you pop back to the main thread to to some UI things.

Comment: @DBoyer i know, but why in sync version exectution completely stop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that code is running on the main event loop, then the `dispatch_group_wait()` is going to block the main queue.  That prevents the synchronous execution of any block on the main queue and leads to deadlock.

You can verify this by pausing into the debugger.   You'll likely see the main thread/queue blocked on the call to wait and a secondary thread/queue blocked on dispatch_sync.

Comment: thank you, deadlock was one of my assumptions, im just not really understand how exactly deadlock works..

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban Ignoring the concurrency issues, you could take the entire block of code and stick it in a `dispatch_async()` onto one of the global concurrent queues and it'd likely "just work" since the `dispatch_group_wait()` would no longer be called from the main thread/queue (the main even loop and the main queue are one in the same;  block one, and you block the other).

Answer (score 2):

Your code is presumably run on the main queue. It dispatches three blocks on the background, then waits until all three blocks have finished running. Since this is done on the main queue, other blocks will only start running on the main queue afterwards, that is after all the three async blocks that you queued up have finished.

Now the third of these three blocks calls the main thread with a sync call. What that means is it adds a block to the main queue, then it waits until the block starts executing, then it waits further until the block finishes executing, then the dispatch_sync call returns to its caller.

Well, that block dispatched to the main thread cannot start executing, because the main thread is busy waiting for the three async blocks to finish, and one of them won't finish because it is waiting for the block dispatched to the main thread to start executing, which it can't because and so on and so on forever. It doesn't actually matter one bit what you are trying to do in the synchronous block, because that block never gets as far as starting to execute.

Comment: thank you, but why you say that code running on main queue? I get global concurrent queue and make it an argument, all that stuff suppose to execute on concurrent queue. Im sorry, that im not understand all clear.